# IOS: Is their anyway to run a command just after file are deployed?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Is their anyway to run a command just after files are deployed via `PASERVER` (and before the install/signing process start)? I found some events like pre-build, post-build and pre-link but all those events are fired before the file are deployed.

it's related to this bug report:
https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-22899

Comment: There's no build phase that supports what you want to happen. Even if there was, it would be during the signing/packaging phase, and it would be a command run on the Mac, however the IDE does not (yet) support those kind of build commands. I expect that this would be something additional to the Deployment Manager, where the user would specify that the library being deployed needs to be signed, rather than having to add more build commands

Comment: @DaveNottage yes this what I understood so I add a new entry: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-22899